# Как прокрутить div вниз с помощью JavaScript и jQuery?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Есть `div` с `overflow: scroll`. Как можно анимированно прокрутить содержимое вниз с помощью JavaScript или jQuery?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

JavaScript, простая прокрутка:

```
element.scrollTop = element.scrollHeight
```

Для jQuery - [ScrollTop](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/). А именно

```
var div = $("#mydiv");
div.scrollTop(div.prop('scrollHeight'));
```

Идея такая же как и в чистом javascript'e - устанавливаем максимально возможное (точнее логически оправданное, так как можно поставить просто 10000) значение прокрутки.

[Здесь](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/) есть красивые демки.